# Length key in dictonary

Tags: python

How can I find out the length of the values of the key? I have code:

```
keys = { 
    'id':[],
    'name': [ ],
    'adress': [],
}

keys['id'].append([1, 2, 3])
keys['name'].append(['nm1', 'nm2', 'test3'])
keys['adress'].append(['adr1', 'adr2'])

for key in keys:
    print(f'{key} : {key.__len__}')
```

It gives me: key : ... (not length and count)
And should:

```
id : 3
name : 3
adress: 2
```

How should I do it?

Comment: There is a function "len" for this.

Comment: `key.__len__()` (you forgot to call the function) or `len(key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. `__len__` is a method, not an attribute.
   You get the length of an iterable using the `len` function:

```
for key in keys:
    print(f'{key} : {len(key)}')
```

[Docs for the built-in len function here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

2. with the code above you get the length of the keys, not the values.

With the loop `for key in keys` you get `id`, `name` and `adress` in the `key` variable. To get the actual values you have [various ways](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), the most common is to use the `.items()` method:

```
for key, value in keys.items():
    print(f'{key} : {len(value)}')
```

3. the way you populate the values will insert 1 item (a list) in each

the `append` method will add the argument you pass in to the list, in your case the whole lists, so the values will be lists containing 1 list each. If you want to have the values to contain `1,2,3` ,`'nm1', 'nm2', 'test3'` and `'adr1', 'adr2'`, you should use the `extend` method ([docs on list methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)):

```
keys['id'].extend([1, 2, 3])
keys['name'].extend(['nm1', 'nm2', 'test3'])
keys['adress'].extend(['adr1', 'adr2'])
```

To get the desired result, this will be your final code:

```
keys = { 
    'id':[],
    'name': [],
    'adress': [],
}

keys['id'].extend([1, 2, 3])
keys['name'].extend(['nm1', 'nm2', 'test3'])
keys['adress'].extend(['adr1', 'adr2'])

for key, value in keys.items():
    print(f'{key} : {len(value)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `extend` method not `append` if you want to add content of the list as a value. And try and read more about how the dictionary works.

```
keys = {
    'id':[],
    'name': [ ],
    'adress': [],
}

keys['id'].extend([1, 2, 3])
keys['name'].extend(['nm1', 'nm2', 'test3'])
keys['adress'].extend(['adr1', 'adr2'])

for key, value in keys.items():
    print(f'{key} : {len(value)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    'id':[],
    'name':[],
    'adress': [],
}

keys['id'].append([1, 2, 3])
keys['name'].append(['nm1', 'nm2', 'test3'])
keys['adress'].append(['adr1', 'adr2'])

for key in keys.keys():
    print(f'{key} : {len(keys[key][0])}')
```